# Where is the central ZFS website now?

Tags: freebsd, zfs, openindiana, illumos, zfsonlinux

[Oracle dumped OpenSolaris](http://blogs.computerworld.com/16741/oracle_dumps_opensolaris) in Fall 2010, and it is unclear if Oracle will continue to publicly release updates to ZFS, except maybe after they release their next major version of Solaris.

FreeBSD now has [ZFS v28](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019541.html) available for testing.

But where did v28 come from? I notice that the [main ZFS website](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+zfs/WebHome) does not show [version 28](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+zfs/28) available. Has this website been abandoned? If so, where is the central website for the ZFS project, so that I can browse the repo, read the mailing lists, read the release notes, etc.

(I realize that OpenSolaris has been dumped by Oracle, and that they are limiting their ZFS releases to the community).

Comment: Quick update: This still isn't 100% settled. While most folks point to the IllumOS project, FreeBSD isn't tracking IllumOS directly, and Oracle Solaris ZFS certainly isn't. We now have IllumOS ZFS, FreeBSD ZFS, Oracle ZFS, and possibly others. Several members of the ZFS community have expressed concern about possible fragmentation of ZFS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Much has happened since I asked this question in October 2010.

As of September 2013, a new collaboration known as OpenZFS will serve as a central site for several ZFS projects. The new site is http://open-zfs.org/ (with a dash)

Today at LinuxCon North America, [Brian Behlendorf and Matthew Ahrens](http://linuxconcloudopenna2013.sched.org/event/b50b23f3ed3bd728fa0052b54021a2cc#.UjiLzT9dwr0) are announcing that members from the illumos, zfsonlinux.org, FreeBSD and MacOSX ZFS communities have created a project called "OpenZFS" to combine their efforts.

Here is the [announcement to the FreeBSD community](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-announce/2013-September/001500.html) from FreeBSD Foundation President Justin Gibbs, and the [announcement to the illumos community](http://www.listbox.com/member/archive/182179/2013/09/sort/time_rev/page/1/entry/8:232/20130917113543:CD3407A8-1FAE-11E3-92D4-A992A2C25D02/) from Matthew Ahrens at Delphix.

Brian Behlendorf (creator of zfsonlinux.org) [announced this on zfs-announce@zfsonlinux.org](https://groups.google.com/a/zfsonlinux.org/forum/#!topic/zfs-announce/lrjfGPNTdIs) today:

> ```
> From: "Behlendorf, Brian D." <behlendorf--->
> To: "zfs-announce@zfsonlinux.org" <zfs-announce@zfsonlinux.org>
> Subject: [zfs-announce] OpenZFS
> Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2013 16:46:40 +0000
> ```
>
> Today we announce OpenZFS: the truly open source successor to the ZFS
>   project.
>
> ZFS is the world's most advanced filesystem, in active development for
>   over a decade. Recent development has continued in the open, and
>   OpenZFS is the new formal name for this open community of developers,
>   users, and companies improving, using, and building on ZFS.  Founded
>   by members of the Linux, FreeBSD, Mac OS X, and illumos communities,
>   including Matt Ahrens, one of the two original authors of ZFS, the
>   OpenZFS community brings together over a hundred software developers
>   from these platforms.
>
> You can read more about OpenZFS at our website: http://open-zfs.org
>   (don't forget the dash!)

---

Old news from December 2012:

Oracle is still pretty closed about it's ZFS development.

As ZFS outside of Oracle is concerned, the primary upstream seems to be illumos. The major players in the non-Oracle ZFS scene all seem to be collaborating on the illumos kernel, which provides ZFS.

- FreeBSD is [tracking illumos ZFS](http://wiki.freebsd.org/ZFS) ("The current vendor of ZFS code for FreeBSD is the Illumos project").
- zfsonlinux.org is [tracking the illumos zfs code](https://groups.google.com/a/zfsonlinux.org/group/zfs-devel/browse_frm/thread/ac22fbf5bc47d38e#)
- [Nexenta and OpenIndiana are cooperating on the Illumian project](https://www.illumos.org/projects/illumian/wiki/What_is_illumian/) at illumos.org
- Joyent's [SmartOS is based on illumos](http://www.joyent.com/products/smartos/smartos-faq/)
- Many core OpenSolaris developers have left Sun/Oracle and work for companies who support illumos. Zoom to minute 40:00:00 of the presentation [Fork Yeah! The Rise and Development of illumos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zRN7XLCRhc), by Bryan Cantrill, VP of Joyent, creator of Dtrace and other things.

Comment: Amusingly, I actually was the first to Answer this Question, and answered that development would continue in IllumOS... which it turns out, is where active open source development is occurring. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zRN7XLCRhc starting at about 0:45:30. There are improvements to ZFS, DTrace, Zones, iSCSI stuff; lots of improvements, and they're gaining momentum.

Comment: Ha! I have that video open in another tab, but not sure if I have an extra hour to watch it. Thanks for highlighting the correct time.

Comment: The whole video is really worth watching if you don't know the history of Solaris, but the last 15 minutes really focus on future development of what was OpenSolaris.

Answer (score 5):

Oracle officially killed OpenSolaris, so the website will not be updated anymore. FreeBSD is working with the [IllumOS](http://www.illumos.org/) project to advance ZFS at this point (their website is still a bit scant on details). I don't know if these changes are derived from actual Solaris 11 development or not, nor if the changes will be merged into the official project (a likely outcome).

Comment: illumos hasn't advanced the version number or changed anything in ZFS code. Zpool version 28 is coming from OpenSolaris published source. http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/fs/zfs.h#348

Comment: Does Illumos intend to fork the project? Or will the incorporate the updates to ZFS after Oracle decides to release their new code?

Comment: From https://www.illumos.org/projects/site/wiki/FAQ:
Will you track Oracle changes?

Yes, we will be tracking ON's source changes and integrating them into our code base.

Comment: Interestingly, according to Bryan Cantrill ( youtube.com/watch?v=-zRN7XLCRhc starting at about 0:45:30 ), Oracle has never officially killed OpenSolaris. Bryan claims that Oracle has never said anything publicly.

Answer (score 4):

The [zfs mailing list](http://mail.opensolaris.org/pipermail/zfs-discuss/) remains on opensolaris.org, and Oracle has not established a new public website for their ongoing ZFS development project.

**Update (2013):** The opensolaris.org website has now been shut down, and Oracle’s [ZFS mailing list](https://java.net/projects/solaris-zfs/lists) has moved to the new [Solaris-ZFS.java.net](http://solaris-zfs.java.net/) website.

Answer (score 4):

For versions up to 28, you can still browse the repository in OpenSolaris web site:

http://src.opensolaris.org/source/history/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/fs/zfs.h

http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/fs/zfs.h#348

**Update:**

This repository has moved to:

https://java.net/projects/solaris/sources/on-src/content/usr/src/uts/common/sys/fs/zfs.h?rev=13149

Comment: So, it seems FreeBSD obtained their v28 from opensolaris.org . And it sounds like Oracle won't provide code for anything above v29 until they release the commercial version of ZFS. They have their own internal repository which has probably advanced beyond v28, but we won't see it for a while.

Comment: Here is something not in zpool version 28 and recently integrated in Solaris code: http://bugs.opensolaris.org/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4854202

Comment: I now see that ZFS Pool version 31 is available at http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+zfs/31 , as of November 2010. I'm not clear if there will be a version 32.

Comment: [All services in the opensolaris.org domain became unavailable](http://web.archive.org/web/20130302151556/http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Main/) after 2013-03-24.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin link updated

Answer (score 1):

For Linux it is http://zfsonlinux.org - there is ZFS Pool Version 28.

Pawel Jakub Dawidek (nickname: PJD) has added the latest open-source ZFS file system version (28) to 
FreeBSD Current. I suppose FreeBSD ZFS's Home is here http://wiki.freebsd.org/ZFS

Above are kernel's modules.
But there is kernel independent application for Linux in user space  http://zfs-fuse.net/ (for 2011-Nov ZFS for Linux 0.7.0 uses Pool Version 23).

Comment: What does the GPL encumbered Linux have to do with FreeBSD or Solaris?

Comment: Do you mean "[What about the licensing issue?](http://zfsonlinux.org/faq.html#WhatAboutTheLicensingIssue)" ?

Comment: No, the Question is asking about FreeBSD, but you started right in with Linux, a completely different OS. If you asked a Question about Linux and I responded that Windows supports whatever you were trying to accomplish, how would that be relevant? I just can't resist the urge to kick Linux anytime it's license holds it back.

Comment: Sorry Chris, my English not too well, I just misunderstanding you. "have to do with" was not clear for me.Absurdly not the GPL but kernel have not providing a way to work with incompatible licenses.

Comment: I'm actually more curious about the upstream ZFS product, irregardless of the OS. http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+zfs/ hasn't had a software release in over a year, and I can't tell if they will ever provide another release outside of the Closed Source releases. Will FreeBSD 9.0, OpenIndiana/Illumos, ZFSOnLinux, ZFS-FUSE ever be able to move beyond ZFS Pool Version 28?

Comment: What?! Matt Dillon isn't porting ZFS to DragonFly.

Comment: You can check it by yourself http://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/en_US/entry/zfs_on_fuse_linux . I supose Jeff Bonwick said the truth. And give me back my points!

Comment: @BBK: Dillon has created his own filesystem (HAMMER), no need for ZFS.